# Get Page content to displayin Bootstrap Modal

Tags: loop, pages, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Ok I'm a relative novice here, and after looking around I still haven't found the answer to my problem. I'm basically trying to link a Bootstrap Modal to some text in a footer (widget), the content of which is sourced from a Page.

I started by placing ALL the text + code in an HTML text widget, but that was too messy (as there's a fair bit of text to include), and have been checking out some other questions like:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347865/wordpress-page-content-in-modal-pop-up

and

[Open WordPress Posts in Bootstrap Modal](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95661/open-wordpress-posts-in-bootstrap-modal)

I hope this makes sense. I have so far been developing my own theme from Bootstrap and figured out much already, but haven't found an answer to this yet.

thanks in advance