# single.php change into a modal popup bootstrap wordpress

Tags: themes

I want to change the modal popup `single.php` be bootstrapping , so when clicked readmore on post , just turn up the single post with the display popup instead to a new page and there are display how many view the post in view .

Comment: It would be good to share your code to show how you are trying to achieve this, so that others can provide feedback and guidance - and also to ensure that your question is clear and answerable.

Answer (score -1):

Check the original answer [Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95661/open-wordpress-posts-in-bootstrap-modal).

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top:20px; min-height:500px;" >
<div class="row">
<?php 
   $labels = new WP_Query(array(
   'post_type' => 'slider', 
   'posts_per_page' => 1000
)); 
 while ( $labels->have_posts() ) : 
 $labels->the_post();
?>
<?php
$src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array(5600,1000 ), false, '' );
?>
<a href="#myModal-<? the_ID(); ?>" data-toggle="modal" >
<div class="span2" style="background: #09F url(<?php echo $src[0]; ?>) center no-repeat !important;">
  <?php the_title();?>
</div>
</a>




<div id="myModal-<? the_ID(); ?>" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">
      <?php the_title();?>
    </h3>
    <p>
      <?php the_content();?>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: single.php code so which one?

Comment: This code is not going to do what the OP asked for, it also too complex and not logical - please ask some questions first to get a better idea and to be sure the question is clear.